# How do I upgrade Linux Mint 8 to Linux Mint 12?

Tags: linux, upgrade, operating-systems, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 8 on my home laptop.  It dual boots Windows Vista.
It's time for an upgrade.  Linux Mint 12 is out and I'd like to replace 8 with it.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mint is based on Ubuntu, the answer is: slowly. 
Ubuntu does not have the feature to jump over versions.

The fastest way to get to Mint 12 is to save your work and reinstall.

Comment: The Mint wiki actually recommends a full re-install.

Comment: Didn't check this but I'm not sure that even Mint 8 -> Mint 9 upgrade is supported at all (being old) which would make the __slow__ and _painful_ upgrade-hell impossible.